# Snowflake if String Pattern replace

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have column which should only contain numbers[0-9], But in some cases we started see alphanumeric[eg:p8eSadfghrc]  values in that column.
I wanna write a condition where if the value is not completely numeric{0-9}, i wanna replace it with another value from another column.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
update t
    set col = <other value>
    where regexp_like(col, '[^0-9]');
```

This updates the data.  You could also just do this in a query:

```
select t.*,
       (case when regexp_like(col, '[^0-9]') then <other value> else col end)
from t;
```

Comment: it fails if if there one number in the value.

Comment: The expression {regexp_like(col, '[^0-9]')} is equivalent to the regex ^[^0-9]$, which is true if and only if col is a string that contains exactly one non-digit. Change it to {regexp_like(col, '.*[^0-9].*')} and you should have what you are seeking.

Comment: @Zoom . . . The expression returns true if any character in the column is NOT a digit.  Even one non-digit will return true.  That is what the question seems to be asking for.

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, I would recommend `try_to_decimal()`. It attempts to convert the number to a decimal value (you control the target precision and scale with arguments) and rturns `null` if that fails:

```
select t.*, case when try_to_decimal(mycol) is null then myothercol else mycol end newcol
from mytable
```

If you want an `update` statement:

```
update mytable
set mycol = myothercol
where try_to_decimal(mycol) is null
```

When given no second and third argument, the number of allowed digits is 38, with 0 decimals (which seems to be what you want).